# Need to map keys to parameters in JSON body

Tags: jquery, mapping

I need to send an HTTP API some JSON in the body like:

```
var body = {
            'param1': 'param1 value',
            'param2': 'param2 value',
            'param3': 'param3 value',
            'param4': 'param4 value',
            'param5': 'param5 value',
            'param6': 'param6 value'
       };
```

But the source I have to build that from is

```
var datasource = {
            'x4001': 'param1 value',
            'jd5jj': 'param2 value',
            'mmmmmoose': 'param3 value',
            'simple': 'param4 value',
            'crayonx3': 'param5 value',
            'hubbabubba': 'param6 value'
       };
```

There *must* be a quick jQuery replace/map function to create my 'body' variable from the datasource JSON - so that 'x4001' becomes 'param1', 'jd5jj' becomes 'param2', etc., etc. to get the body I crave?

in other answers I've seen, I see things like:

```
function renameProperty(obj, fromKey, toKey) {
  obj[toKey] = obj[fromKey];
  delete obj[fromKey];
}

addObjectResponse.forEach(obj => renameProperty(obj, 'SP02', 'O2'));
```

But my JavaScript / jQuery just doesn't understand *anything* with `=>` in it - (which looks like LINQ statements from C#).

So - either I'm using the wrong jQuery, or I need a different solution?

Comment: in the samples provided in the answer, I see things like :   body.forEach(obj => renameProperty(obj, 'Title', 'requestor name')); or addObjectResponse.forEach(obj => renameProperty(obj, 'SP02', 'O2')); ... well my javascript / jquery doesn't understand anything like '=>' it just chokes, so those answers don't work

Comment: It also demonstrates the setting of the new key and removal of the old key, constituting a 'rename'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're renaming all the keys in `datasource`, it's simplest to define a "key map" and use that to look up new names from old:

```js
var keymap = {
  x4001: "param1",
  jd5jj: "param2",
  mmmmmoose: "param3",
  simple: "param4",
  crayonx3: "param5",
  hubbabubba: "param6"
};

var datasource = {
  x4001: "param1 value",
  jd5jj: "param2 value",
  mmmmmoose: "param3 value",
  simple: "param4 value",
  crayonx3: "param5 value",
  hubbabubba: "param6 value"
};

var body = {};

for (var key in datasource) 
  body[keymap[key]] = datasource[key];

console.log(body);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.stringify()` and `String.prototype.replace()` with `RegExp` `/"([\w\d])+"(?=:)/g`

```js
var n = 0;
var datasource = {
  'x4001': 'param1 value',
  'jd5jj': 'param2 value',
  'mmmmmoose': 'param3 value',
  'simple': 'param4 value',
  'crayonx3': 'param5 value',
  'hubbabubba': 'param6 value'
};
var body = JSON.parse(
             JSON.stringify(datasource)
             .replace(/"([\w\d]+)"(?=:)/g, function(match) {
               return `"param${++n}"`
             })
           );

console.log(body);
```

```js
var n = 0;
var arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];
var datasource = {
  'x4001': 'param1 value',
  'jd5jj': 'param2 value',
  'mmmmmoose': 'param3 value',
  'simple': 'param4 value',
  'crayonx3': 'param5 value',
  'hubbabubba': 'param6 value'
};
var body = JSON.parse(
             JSON.stringify(datasource)
             .replace(/"([\w\d]+)"(?=:)/g, function(match) {
               return `"${arr[n++]}"`
             })
           );

console.log(body);
```

Comment: well, the name param1 isn't necessarily 'param1' - it could be 'justified date'

Comment: @RobertAchmann Then you can use an array of values to set replacement sting `return arr[n++]`

Comment: @RobertAchmann See updated post